# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 18 (char 17)

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I am using gunicorn + Flask + Docker with async gevent workers. My application receives a request with a json body that contains a base64 encoded image. I then load this json, extract the image using its key and continue with my processing before return the response. This works fine, but for some requests I do not receive the full json body and get the error shown above. What could be the problem here?

```
from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify, request
import json

@app.route("/ocr", methods=["POST"])
def ocr():
    data = json.loads(request.data) # error happens here
     ...
```

gunicorn command:

```
gunicorn wsgi:app --bind  0.0.0.0:443 --log-level=debug --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm --workers=4 --worker-class gevent --reload --timeout 300 --graceful-timeout 300 --log-file=-
```

Note that my endpoint is called by an app (users from different locations/phones/networks)

I noticed that I am missing some of the json body that I was expecting for these images, which I believe is the reason why I get this error when loading the json. It seems that I receive only a part of the request before the connection terminates (the reason being not visible).

Is this an issue of slow connections/ large json body? if so how can I fix this to handle such requests?